# Sails JS - How to install Sails JS HTML documentation on Mac?

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

Would you please help me to install Sails Js documentation on Mac? The documentation repository is on [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs), I also installed doc-templater using `npm install doc-templater` as states [here](https://github.com/uncletammy/doc-templater).

Thanks for your time.